# Не могу соединится с JSON api MoySklad

Tags: json, мойсклад-api, moysklad-pos-api

Собираюсь подключить МойСклад к моему приложению на Qlik Sense. Авторизацию  прошел успешно, однако выдает следующею ошибку при попытки подключения к апи:

`{"errors":[{"error":"Неопознанный путь: http://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1","code":1002,"moreInfo":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc#обработка-ошибок-1002"}]}`

"Ресурс не найден"

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы обратились к корню, а нужно к ресурсам - попробуйте сразу запросить интересующий ресурс.